# perl regex returns numbers and no string

Tags: regex, perl, regex-greedy

Im trying to remove all the empty lines from a string. My string is a paragraph that has a lot of random empty lines and I am trying to clean it up.

eg:

```
this is an example

lots of empty

lines

in the paragraph
```

should be

```
this is an example
lots of empty
lines 
in the paragraph
```

The code i am currently using only returns random digits.. its as if its doing a word count or something.

e.g

```
output = 567
```

or

```
output = 221
```

thats all it returns, no words, no paragraph

my code looks like this

It was first suppose to match and then print all the words after the match
and then I wanted to remove all the empty lines to clean up the output

```
 my ($shorten) = $origin =~ /word to match\s*(.*)$/s;

 my ($cleanlines) = $shorten =~ s/\n//g;
```

the $shorten part works perfectly, but $cleanlines part doesnt work.

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
my ($cleanlines) = $shorten =~ s/\n//g;
```

deletes all the newline characters in `$shorten` and stores the number of changes made in `$cleanlines`

If you want to delete empty lines from `$shorten` then you must write this instead

```
(my $cleanlines = $shorten) =~ s/^\s*\n//gm;
```

Answer (score 0):

`my ($shorten) = $origin =~ /word to match\s*(.*)$/s;` worked because you used capturing parentheses in your regex, and whatever was matched by `(*.)` ended up in `$shorten`.

To remove blank lines from your string, you can use this simple regex:

```
$shorten =~ s/\n+\n/g;
```

The substitution will be performed on the `$shorten` variable. If you want to keep `$shorten` unchanged and have the cleaned up lines in a new variable, then simply copy the contents of `$shorten` to a new variable and perform the substitution on it:

```
my $cleanlines = $shorten;
$cleanlines =~ s/\n+/\n/g;
```

Comment: That won't remove lines that are empty except for spaces or tabs, but it may be all that's required